# Should we really reuse global variables in AWS lambda runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, web, aws-lambda, connection

I'm quoting this very shady paragraph from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) regarding performance tips on AWS-lambda service.

According to AWS team:

> Take advantage of Execution Context reuse to improve the performance
>   of your function. Make sure any externalized configuration or
>   dependencies that your code retrieves are stored and referenced
>   locally after initial execution. Limit the re-initialization of
>   variables/objects on every invocation. Instead use static
>   initialization/constructor, global/static variables and singletons.
>   Keep alive and reuse connections (HTTP, database, etc.) that were
>   established during a previous invocation

let's ignore for a second the evil idea of **intentionally** declaring variables as **global, static and opt for singletones*** (personally speaking, this is one of the most irresponsible advises one can give) my main concern is the use of **open connections**.

My questions are:

1. what happens if , eg, the connection times out between one lambda invocations to another? how does the AWS runtime "knows" no to re-use that connection?
2. what happens if the connection is buffered? meaning there are residues from a previous invocations?
3. is this advice (re-using connections across invocations) really holds in real life? it's seems very buggish to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. what happens if , eg, the connection times out between one lambda invocations to another? how does the AWS runtime "knows" no to re-use
>      that connection?
> 2. what happens if the connection is buffered? meaning there are residues from a previous invocations?

The AWS runtime doesn't "know" how to handle that at all. Your Lambda function would need to know that by checking if the connection is still valid, and handling the situation if it is no longer valid.

> 3. is this advice (re-using connections across invocations) really holds in real life? it's seems very buggish to me.

Given the realities of the AWS Lambda runtime environment, this advice is absolutely valid if your concern is to reduce cold start times for your Lambda function invocations. However it can certainly result in issues with things like connections to relational databases, which is why Amazon has released the [AWS Aurora Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html).

I generally try to follow this advice for caching data in Lambda functions, such as initializing a data structure by reading a database table or loading an S3 object into memory for example, but I've found the issues with globally scoped database connections in Lambda functions to bee more trouble than it is worth, but if your Lambda function has very frequent invocations it might be worth it to you.